# Why isn't a function parameter used here?

Tags: c++, parameters, arguments

I'm going through this tutorial:
https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/how-to-design-your-first-programs/
I noticed the author didn't use a parameter in this function:

```
int getUserInput()
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer ";
    int input{};
    std::cin >> input;

    return input;
}
```

Would it be okay to do something like this?

```
int getUserInput(int input)
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer ";
    std::cin >> input;

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Ask yourself this: What would the caller of the function pass into that argument?

Comment: What's the line? "your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could that they didn't stop to think if they should." Which "okay" are you asking about -- could or should?

Comment: @JaMiT there are things mankind was not meant to know.

Comment: Note that in your second example `int getUserInput(int input)` the `input` parameter is passed by value meaning the calling program provides a value to this function and the value is copied so if the getUserInput() function changed `input` the function calling it would not see that change. As a result it's rather pointless to have to pass a value to a function that will not be used.

Comment: @drescherjm but the changed value is returned. It's ok, as long the returned value is copied back by the caller. It doesn't make any sense, but generally not making sense is OK, no? </sarcasm>

Comment: The better parameter I can think of here, is to use `std::istream` instead of `std::cin` hardcoded inside that function :-P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would work, but it wouldn't make much sense.

The first version of your function is used something like this:

```
int some_number = getUserInput();
```

That makes sense; the caller isn't providing any input to the function, so it takes no parameters.

---

The second version takes a parameter though, so the caller has to provide it.  The function doesn't actually *do* anything with that value though.  All of the following behave exactly the same:

```
int some_number1 = getUserInput(0);
int some_number2 = getUserInput(123456);
int some_number3 = getUserInput(some_number2);
```

It makes no sense for the caller to provide a parameter to the function since the function doesn't use it at all.